# How to make a block listing taxonomy terms in a hierarchy (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

So I have a taxonomy hierarchy (assigned to blog posts as free tags) that looks, say, something like this (apologies, it's totally arbitrary for testing purposes right now):

[image: Example taxonomy terms]

I'd like to create a block that simply outputs what I see in this menu: The taxonomy terms, ordered into a heirarchy, with links to the taxonomy term page (listing all content that this term is attached to). Ideally also, a count for the number of nodes each term is attached to.

At first I tried defining a block and used `taxonomy_get_tree` but that was a bit of a deal trying to recursively turn the output of that function into something I could work with. I also tried views, bringing in taxonomy terms but I couldn't get them to display as a hierarchy, or get the count to show.

So I'm a bit stumped. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked out the taxonomy menu module - http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu 
This module does everything you mentioned as well as outputting the number.

Comment: Perfect - I actually spent some time looking for D7 modules of this ilk but somehow overlooked this. Thankyou.